# SQL insert field, with value of other auto increment field + value

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment

It might sound complicated, but it's not.
I have a table called "orders", with fields:

```
id INT(11) auto_increment,
realid INT(14)
```

Now, I want at every insert into this table, do something like:

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, id+1000);
```

However I'll be doing it on shop which is currently online, and I want to change everything in 5 minutes. Will something like this work? If not, how do I do that?

Comment: why have the id field if you're only going to insert NULL into it?

Comment: So you want to insert pairs like (1, 1001), (2, 1002) and so on? Why would you want to do that? You can count the "realid" at client or in select if you need to, otherwise you bring redundancy to your db.

Comment: @Tahbaza - it's to save time. Instead of INSERT INTO orders(realid) VALUES (1001), I can write null, and It'll automatically increase. @Frantisek - As I said, site is online, and now I have to work around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think a simpler solution would be a calculated column presuming your DBMS supports it (This is using SQL Server syntax, although the MySql syntax should be nearly identical except that you would use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of `Identity(1,1)`):

```
Create Table Foo    (
                    Id int not null identity(1,1)
                    , Name varchar(50)
                    , Bar As Id + 1000 
                    )
```

Of course, you could also just do it in the presentation or business tier instead of the database.